# Putting Shopify Liquid stylesheet links in body

Tags: shopify

From an encapsulation point of view linking section-specific stylesheets makes a lot of sense using `link` in the body; however, using `<link>` in the body is considered bad practice. Should I have all the stylesheets for every single section in the `<head>` or is using `<link>` inside Liquid sections a better idea because body linking is a bad idea?

### All stylesheets in `<head>` approach

```
<head>
    {{  'theme-wide-styles.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
    {% if page.url == '/pages/page-with-some-section' %}
        {{ 'section-stylesheet.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
    {% endif %}
</head>
<body>
    {%- section 'some-section' %}
</body>
```

**Pros:** Considered better practice

**Cons:** `<head>` gets messy with a large number of templates

---

### Section stylesheet in Liquid section approach

```
<head>
    {{  'theme-wide-styles.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
</head>
<body>
    {%- section 'some-section' %}
</body>
```

**some-section.liquid**

```
{{ 'section-stylesheet.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
<div>
    section content.....
</div>
```

**Pros:** Uses encapsulation to create a cleaner layout

**Cons:** `<link>` stylesheets in body while technically not incorrect, are considered bad practice.

---

MDN says it's bad practice, but I feel like with Liquid it makes it a lot of sense for complex sites.

**MDN:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link

Comment: related: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/341460/188407 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/50154225/2234742

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister interesting, thanks for the links. So, those answers seem to suggest using `style` in the body is very situational. I didn't know it was used fairly often in CMSs, but makes sense. With the WHATWG 'living' HTML standard it sounds like `<style>` is not allowed, but after some digging it looks like `<link>` is allowed as long as it has a 'body-ok' `itemprop` or `rel` https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#allowed-in-the-body

Comment: Very interesting. This is the first I've heard of that `body-ok` attribute. In any case, I use lots of stylesheets in body for my templated Jekyll site, and I don't worry about it, so there's one data point.

Comment: For anyone passing through, the `stylesheet_tag` in `{{ 'section-stylesheet.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}` produce a 'body-ok' `rel` attribute. So, technically even with the change in HTML standards, `<link>` in the body looks safe for now. Whether it actually should go in the body seems pretty situational and opinionated. But, in my case and with news sites using this practice widely already, I feel safe adding using `<links>` in interest of readable/maintainable Liquid code.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister okay, that makes me feel better. "body-ok" isn't an attribute, I probably didn't describe it well. I believe it's something like a requirement based on the attribute values. So, a `link` with `rel="stylesheet"` is considered "body-ok". https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#body-ok